# If content is too long, scroll horizontally with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

**Only for mobile**, I am scrolling my existing nav-tabs. 
But depending on the tab content you don't even recognize that there is more content to come on the right hand side from time to time. I would love to show ellipsis dots - but text-overflow: ellipsis does not seem to work here. Any help would be appreciated!

Result shoud be => "Basel  Frankf...."

```css
#container {
  width: 200px; 
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.nav-tabs {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}

.nav-tabs>a {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Basel</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Frankfurt</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Hamburg</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">München</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Hamburg</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set text-overflow on a container element. It would have to be set on an element that directly has text in it. I don't think this is exactly what you want but it would work. It may at least give you an idea to work toward another solution.

```css
#container {
    width: 200px; 
  }
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  li {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  .nav-tabs {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
  }

  .nav-tabs>a {
    float: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Basel</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Frankfurt</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Hamburg</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">München</a>
      <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Hamburg</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot replace the <li> content and merge it to one. For a static page that would have been a nice solution anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Text overflow ellipsis working on the content, not child elements.
For the mobile version use another way like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp

Comment: Yeah, have to talk to the responsible people here. Doing it in a vertical way would be the better idea. Thx!

Comment: They say it's a problem on some pages where we have 5 or 6 tabs. It's getting to long then ... rolleyes.....

Comment: No, it's not a problem because when it's getting long then you put there scrollbar so it's working perfectly.